# Trying to list certain dates on SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of dates in a table

```
DATES
----------
10-SEP-03
10-SEP-03
15-SEP-03
15-SEP-03
17-SEP-03
18-SEP-03
30-SEP-03
01-OCT-03
01-OCT-03
05-OCT-03
08-OCT-03
05-MAY-03
10-JUN-03
12-JUN-03
```

and I would like it to display it while excluding ones with october, how can i accomplish that?
I have tried out where dates `!= '%OCT___'`; but that didnt work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is Oracle (since you did not state, but show SQLPLUS), and you have a table called table1:

```
select * 
    from table1
    where extract( month from dates ) <> 10
```

The format that is shown in SQLPLUS is the display format, not the internal representation in the database.  The format for a session is controlled by the NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting see [here for details](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm).

For future reference, it is bad practice to compare a date field with a literal that does not conform to the date format.  For example, if someone sets the NLS_DATE_FORMAT to 'MM/DD/YYYY' then using "OCT" will not work, as the default format is expecting "10" as the month value.  Always best to use the TO_DATE function to convert your literal values proper DATE types.

Answer (score 0):

OldProgrammer is absolutely right, and his answer will work in Oracle & PostgreSQL. And just in case someone is using T-SQL, Access, mySQL, or SQLite out there, it would look like this:

```
Select *

From Table1

Where MONTH(dates) <> 10
```

Comment: The query in OldProgrammer's answer is actually standard ANSI SQL (and works with more than just the two DBMS you mentioned)